# How to locate web element (Xpath: multiple conditions)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate a specific element with XPath (for a script that I work on in Python with Selenium module). I've looked it up on the internet but I can't find solution to my problem, which is:

there is a table that consists of many 'tr'. Each 'tr' consist of couple 'td' that share the same class (namely:"Zelle"). I'd like to find a 'tr' that meets two conditions. First it has to contain text "auto" in one td, then it has to contain text "Abge" in ANOTHER td- finally it has to contain "a" element of class "Tabelle".

I wrote something like this:

```
("//tr//td[@class='Zelle'][contains(.,'auto')]//following::td[@class='Zelle'][contains(.,'Abge')]//following::a[@class='Tabelle']")
```

But when I try it in developers console I get all tr's with td that contain "auto" (even if the second td doesn't contain "Abge"). How to write statement that would return ONLY tr's with BOTH "auto" and "Abge"?

Sample HTML:

```
<tr>
<td class="Zelle">auto</td>
<td class="Zelle">Abge</td>
<td class="Zelle">Some characters</td>
<td class="Zelle">
<a class="Tabelle" href="blablahblah.aspx?xxxx=Number"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Zelle">auto</td>
<td class="Zelle">Abge</td>
<td class="Zelle">Some characters</td>
<td class="Zelle">
<a class="Tabelle" href="blablahblah.aspx?xxxx=Number"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Zelle">auto</td>
<td class="Zelle">Some text(but no "Abge")</td>
<td class="Zelle">Some characters</td>
<td class="Zelle">
<a class="Tabelle" href="blablahblah.aspx?xxxx=Number"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="Zelle">some text (but not "auto")</td>
<td class="Zelle">Abge</td>
<td class="Zelle">Some characters</td>
<td class="Zelle">
<a class="Tabelle" href="blablahblah.aspx?xxxx=Number"></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you share HTML sample for the same?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is the actual problem- what commend should I use to select only those 'tr' that contain BOTH "auto" and "Abge" (in different 'td' that are part of the same tr). When I used xpath stated above it selects all 'tr' that have td that contains "auto", even if the second 'td' doesn't contain "Abge".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below XPath

```
//tr[td[contains(., "auto")] and td[contains(., "Abge")] and .//a[@class="Tabelle"]]
```

Comment: doesn't work, I'll ad sample code of this website in the question, as you suggested.

Comment: What can I say- Thank you very much! Works perfectly!